# How to execute a WHERE clause in a view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to show some data coming from a database in a page (VIEW) using the WHERE clause as a variable.

The select is pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms = $term;
```

In the model I have created following code:

```
class Get_collection_data extends CI_Model {

public function get_terms ($term){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$term");
return $query;
```

Controller:

```
class Admin_collection extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();

$this->load->model('get_collection_data');  
}


$data['house_items'] =  $this->get_collection_data->get_terms($term);
```

Obviously the script does not work.
My question is: how can I pass the $terms in the view? $term has different values which I can get directly from the view. How can I execute the WHERE clause in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error within your query into Active Records

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$term");
                                                                   ^^^
```

it should be

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$term'");
                                                                   ^^^^
```

or you can use Active Records as

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('terms',$term);
$result = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
return $result;
```

and you can pass your values within view as

```
$data['terms'] = $this->model->modelFunction($terms);
$this->load->view('your_view_file', $data);
```

and can access this on view page as `$terms` or just to check on your view   whats the output just use `print_r($terms)`

Comment: Hi Uchiha...I am bit confused. I do not understand how to execute the WHERE clause in the view.

Comment: Where did you get stuck you. Please elaborate your error's or where you get stuck its difficult to understand what you really want it make some relevant scenario for the respective

Comment: According to your answer above. First of all I am getting this error:
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: terms

Filename: controllers/admin_collection.php

Line Number: 46

Comment: In the view page if I write this code nothing it happens:

foreach($terms as $row){
echo $row->item;
}

Comment: Try to `print_r($data['terms'])` within your controller and check are you getting value within it

Comment: I get this result: array()

Comment: It seems you were not getting value within your query try to `echo $terms` are you getting value with this variable

Comment: No, I did not get values.

Comment: You need to pass or to check why you were not getting values within `$terms`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the SQL has syntax error:

Correct:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$terms");
```

To:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$terms'"); // Notice ' after $terms.
```

Secondly, we are not supposed to call model functions from views.

In CodeIgniter, you can do it, but, still, it is against standards.

Normally, we do all data operations in models, fetch the data in Controllers.

And then, pass the data to views by controllers.

```
$data['termsHTML'] = $this->model->modelFunction($terms);
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

Then, you will print the `termsHTML` in view as `echo $termsHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms =  '$term");
```

to this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE terms = '$term'");
```

error occur because **Empty data passing** to you view. (**Syntax Error**)

in controller.

```
$data['house_items'] =  $this->get_collection_data->get_terms($term);
$this->load->view('Your_View_Name',$data)
```

in view

```
foreach ($house_items as $new_house_items)
{
  //example to point data.
  echo $new_house_items['name'];//example code to understand.
}
```

Comment: Hi Abdulla. My question is: how can I pass the $term in the view? the loop in the view does not select the related item according to the $term.

Comment: I saw it. Unfortunately the script does not show the data with the related $term.

Comment: can you give me your full code of controller and what are the database field you trying to get

Comment: class Admin_collection extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  
   $this->load->model('get_collection_data'); 
     
 
 
 }


$data['house_items'] =  $this->get_collection_data->get_terms($term);
$this->load->view('my_view',$data)


}

Comment: In teh VIEW I have following code:

foreach ($house_items as $row){
 
  echo $row->item;
}

Comment: I did not understand yet how to pass the WHERE clause $term in the view in order to execute the query.

Comment: in your view use `echo $row['database_field_name']`

Comment: if you database column has **id**, **name** and **contact**. if you want show it in view echo `$row['id']`, or `$row['name']`, `$row['contact']`

Answer (score 0):

to Pass  $terms in the view use

```
 $data["term"] = $term;
 $this->load->view("Your_view", $data);
```

In you view you can use `$term` for getting your condition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How can I exactly use it to get condition in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Active Record](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) CodeIgniter.

**Model**

```
public function get_terms ($term){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table')->where('terms',  $terms);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

**Controller**

Check data if not empty before sending to view.

```
$data['house_items'] =  $this->get_collection_data->get_terms($term);
$data["term"] = (!empty($data['house_items']) ? $data['house_items'] : "" );
$this->load->view("term_view", $data);
```